# text box alteration

Tags: javascript, html, css

I posted a question earlier, and for somereason this wouldn't let me comment so I figured I would post again. My website is http://www.spencedesign.netau.net/singaporehomemenu.html. I have two problems that I have no Idea how to fix. First, originally without the javascript, my the actual menu not the button thing used to have the words where they are on the screen, but they were at the bottom of the box, and the box was above them. I don't know how the javascript messed that up, but somehow it did, and I tried using margins and padding in all the spots that I could, and nothing worked. My other problem is that upon opening the page, I want the menu hidden until you click on it, I am not sure how to remedy that either. Sorry if this is a stupid question, I have only been learning html and css for a few weeks, and I have no idea about javascript. Thanks!

EDITED PROBLEM PLEASE HELP:
Sorry about not being clarifying. The box used to look like this (except formatted like the other one on the website) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSnzV.png). See the links are on the bottom, and the top of the menu box is lined up with the top of the menu button. But instead as you can see the actual words are in the right spot, but the background of the box is shifted downward, and it is not just some simple padding or margin error. I fixed it, but it isn't a proficient fix. I resorted to using postion absolute

Comment: _"I want the menu hidden until you click on it"_ How can you click on a hidden thing? (OK, I know what you really mean: just give the menu div a starting style of `display:none`, or add `menu.style.display = "none"` from an `onload` handler.)

Comment: I tried, but couldn't decipher what you mean about the positioning of the menu box.  Can you rephrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the menu initially, just give it the CSS property `display: none`.

```
<div id="menu" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

Comment: Or, better, add `display:none;` to the style-sheet, given that `#menu` already has an entry with some other settings.